# Convert Hibernate @Formula to JOOQ field

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, dsl, jooq

I am rewriting entire DB access layer from Hibernate to JOOQ and I face following issue.

One of JPA models is annotated with [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) annotation as follows:

```
@Formula("fee1 + fee2 + fee3 + fee4")
private BigDecimal fee5;
```

Later in the code, a JPA query is made against the database which compares **fee5** to parameter:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE fee5 > input;
```

How can above query be translated to JOOQ DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue with following JOOQ query:

```
BigDecimal input = ...;
Field<BigDecimal> fee5 = TABLE.FEE1.add(TABLE.FEE2).add(TABLE.FEE3).add(TABLE.FEE4).as("fee5");
Condition cond = fee5.greaterThan(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from jOOQ 3.17, the most direct translation of a `@Formula` would be a [virtual client side computed column](https://blog.jooq.org/create-dynamic-views-with-jooq-3-17s-new-virtual-client-side-computed-columns/), i.e. a synthetic column that is attached to a table and produces an expression in every query that projects the column.

That way, you could just write:

```java
ctx.select(...)
   .from(TABLE)
   .where(FEE5.gt(input))
   .fetch();
```

But you don't strictly need this feature. Every jOOQ query is a [dynamic SQL query](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), so you can add whatever expression you choose to refactor into a utility method to any query you like. For example:

```java
ctx.select(...)
   .from(TABLE)
   .where(fee5(TABLE).gt(input))
   .fetch();
```

With:

```java
Field<BigDecimal> fee5(MyTable t) {
    return t.FEE1.add(t.FEE2).add(t.FEE3).add(t.FEE4);
}
```