# Table re-shaping

Tags: java, jooq

I'm working with very badly designed database and I need to re-shape tables before writing my queries.

Here are my common problems:

- timestamps have been splitted over two columns (one for date, another for time).
- some string columns have been also splitted over multiple columns.
- most strings have fixed-length & blank padded, so I need to trim them.

I first think about adapting output of Jooq Generator. But looking at `createField(...)` method, it appends field to `fields0()` which is package-private. Which makes `SELECT *` querying all (and only) "raw" fields, not the re-shaped ones.

What it is the best way to declare statically (ie class/member) or dynamically (ie code) such model ?

Comment: Ideally, you would be writing a view directly in the database. Is that an option?

Comment: For sure, it should have. But unfortunately, administrative operations are quite complex on my environments. More, query definition is very volatile and will change over time.

Comment: I know the feeling. Just checking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally obtain the result using the following classes (I have ignored schema handling, binding & conversion for simplification).

*However, it relies on injecting a custom class inside jOOQ packages & reusing internal code. Which can cause security (if JARs / packages are sealed) and maintainability problems. This why I don't consider it as valid but possible answer to the problem*

jOOQ hack :

```
package org.jooq.impl
public abstract class Projection<R extends Record> extends TableImpl<R> {

  public static final <R extends Record, T> TableField<R, T> newField(String name, DataType<T> type, Table<R> table) {
    return newField(name, type, table, null, null, null);
  }
  public static final <R extends Record, T, X, U> TableField<R, U> newField(String name, DataType<T> type, Table<R> table, String comment, Converter<X, U> converter, Binding<T, X> binding) {
    final Binding<T, U> actualBinding = DefaultBinding.newBinding(converter, type, binding);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final DataType<U> actualType =
        converter == null && binding == null
      ? (DataType<U>) type
      : type.asConvertedDataType(actualBinding);

    final TableFieldImpl<R, U> tableField = new TableFieldImpl<R, U>(name, actualType, table, comment, actualBinding);

   return tableField;
  }

  protected Projection(String name) {
    this(name, null);
  }
  protected Projection(String name, Table<R> aliased) {
    super(name, null, aliased);
  }

  protected <T> TableField<R,T> field(String name, DataType<T> type) {
    return newField(name, type, this);
  }
  protected <T,F extends Field<T>> F add(F field) {
    fields0().add(field);
    return field;
  }
  protected Fields<R> getFields() {
    return fields0();
  }
}
```

My abstraction for common problems :

```
package com.company.model.jooq;
public abstract class MyProjection<R extends Record> extends Projection<R> {
  /**
   * Unique version identifier for serialization.
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected Field<String> trimmed(String name) {
    return DSL.trim(newField(name, SQLDataType.VARCHAR, this)).as(name);
  }
  protected Field<String> joined(String name, String... names) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Field<String>[] fields = new Field[names.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      fields[i] = newField(names[i], SQLDataType.VARCHAR, this);
    }
    return DSL.trim(DSL.concat(fields)).as(name);
  }
  protected Field<Timestamp> timestamp(String suffix) {
    return DSL.function("timestamp", SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP,
        newField("DT_" + suffix, SQLDataType.DATE, this),
        newField("TI_" + suffix, SQLDataType.TIME, this)
    ).as("TS_" + suffix);
  }

  protected MyProjection(String name) {
    super(name);
  }
  protected MyProjection(String name, Table<R> aliased) {
    super(name, aliased);
  }
}
```

A table model example :

```
package com.company.model.jooq;
public class MyProjectedTable extends MyProjection<Record> {
  public final TableField<Record, Integer> ID        = add(field("ID", SQLDataType.INTEGER));
  public final Field<Timestamp>            TS_CREATE = add(timestamp("CREATE"));
  public final Field<Timestamp>            TS_UPDATE = add(timestamp("UPDATE"));
  public final TableField<Record, String>  NAME      = add(field("NAME", SQLDataType.VARCHAR));
  public final Field<String>               LABEL     = add(trimmed("LABEL"));
  public final Field<String>               COMMENT   = add(joined("COMMENT", "COMMENT1", "COMMENT2", "COMMENT3"));
}
```

Comment: Interesting. You essentially implemented Hibernate's `@Formula` annotation, more or less...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it breaks jOOQ idiom as it's not SQL. But I was looking for a library that sit somewhere between jOOQ and ORM for :
- Query definition
- SQL generation (with very good control over it)
- Lazy fetching (iteration, as I need to browse over 500k records)
- Non-static output model (ie entity)

I'm pretty sure that my needs is closer to jOOQ than ORM. So, I have started to play with jOOQ. I should also have written plain query (using full DSL API capabilitiy), but query building should have been pretty uncleared due to number of columns (>100) and tables/suqueries (>8) to join.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't break "jOOQ idiom". jOOQ has [`CustomTable`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/) and other types for similar use-cases. Only, these things are quite low-level right now. We have a [feature requests for views "written in jOOQ"](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1969). I'll write up an answer about that later on.

Answer (score 1):

In JPA, what you're trying to do is modelled using the [`@Embedded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html) annotation. Or in Hibernate - with a bit more sophistication, the [`@Formula`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166107/convert-hibernate-formula-to-jooq-field) annotation. jOOQ has similar features on the roadmap:

- Implement "jOOQ views": https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1969
- Support for nested records in SQL: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2360
- Support for "fetch groups": https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2530

As of jOOQ 3.5, you will have to implement this support yourself, though. The [approach that you've chosen yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28317490/521799) looks quite (re-)useful.