# Convert Hibernate @Formula (case ) to JOOQ field

Tags: sql, hibernate, dsl, jooq

I am rewriting entire DB access layer from Hibernate to JOOQ and I face following issue.

One of JPA models is annotated with @Formula annotation as follows:

```
@Formula("(case"
    + "  when field1 >= 0.5 then 2"
    + "  when field1 >= 0.2 then 1"
    + "  else 0 end)")
private int field2;
```

I saw the following question :
[Convert Hibernate @Formula to JOOQ field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166107/convert-hibernate-formula-to-jooq-field)
but it did not really help

How can above query be translated to JOOQ DSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jOOQ manual's section about the `CASE` expression will help you:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions

Essentially, the expression that you should build will look like this:

```
Field<Integer> field2 = 
DSL.when(TABLE.FIELD1.ge(0.5), 2)
   .when(TABLE.FIELD1.ge(0.2), 1)
   .otherwise(0);
```

Of course, jOOQ is not an annotation-based API, so you cannot use an annotation to automatically generate that value on your target entities. Just like in SQL, you would be using the above `field2` expression in all the relevant queries, e.g.

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(TABLE.ID, TABLE.FIELD1, field2)
   .from(TABLE)
   .fetch();
```

Note that starting from jOOQ 3.17, you can also attach such expressions directly to your generated code to have a more `@Formula` style experience in jOOQ. The feature is called [virtual client side computed columns](https://blog.jooq.org/create-dynamic-views-with-jooq-3-17s-new-virtual-client-side-computed-columns/).

Comment: Works fine, but what is the difference between DSL and DSLcontext?

Comment: `DSL` contains static DSL methods, whereas `DSLContext` contains DSL methods in the context of a `Configuration`. [More info here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/)